# Org mode weirdness with org-export-with-sub-superscripts

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I got sick of adding `#+OPTIONS: ^:{}` to the top of all of my `.org` files, so I thought I'd try to get that behavior once and for all by editing my `.emacs` file. Based on available documentation, it seems like

```
(setq org-export-with-sub-superscripts "{}")
```

would achieve the same behavior as `#+OPTIONS: ^:{}`, although when I do the `(setq ...` thing on its own, both `A_B` and `A_{B}` are rendered as `A<sub>B</sub>` in the HTML output. To ensure `org-export-with-sub-superscripts` is the right variable, I tried

```
(setq org-export-with-sub-superscripts nil)
```

which caused `A_B` to be rendered as `A_B` and `A_{B}` to be rendered as `A_{B}`—exactly what you'd expect. I've also tried `'"{}"`, and `(setq org-use-sub-superscripts "{}")` (with and without quoting `"{}"`), neither of which worked.

I had this problem in Org mode 7.9.3, and it's followed me to 8.2.10. Any ideas what I'm doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must write instead:

```
(setq org-use-sub-superscripts '{})
```

Comment: I use Emacs through the terminal, so I was mostly just concerned about the behavior when exporting to HTML, so `(setq org-export-with-sub-superscripts '{})`works for that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to define a template based on your #+OPTIONS

example:

here I have a template file to export to HTML which contains

```
---- level-0-html.org--------
#+DRAWERS: HIDDEN PROPERTIES STATE CABECALHO COMENTARIOS

:CABECALHO:
# # desabilita o superscrito/subscrito  | não exporta programação
#+OPTIONS: ^:nil p:nil

#+OPTIONS: tags:nil
#+STARTUP: showeverything

#+STYLE: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/leslie.css" />

#+LANGUAGE:  pt_BR
#+OPTIONS:   H:2 num:t toc:f \n:nil @:t ::t |:t ^:t -:t f:t *:t <:t
#+EXPORT_SELECT_TAGS: export
#+EXPORT_EXCLUDE_TAGS: noexport
#+TAGS: export(e) noexport(n) 
#+LINK_UP:   
#+LINK_HOME: 
:END:
#+TITLE: 
#+AUTHOR: Leslie H. Watter
#+EMAIL:  
#+DATE:
------------------------------------------------
```

and in my org-file that I'll export I have:

```
----- presentation.org ------
#+SETUPFILE: ~/org/templates/level-0-html.org
#+TITLE: Gerência de Redes
#+AUTHOR: Leslie H. Watter
#+EMAIL:  hooorayyyy @ my domain .com 

* Gerência de Redes 
(and here goes the entire file)
------
```

This way I get a consistent way of exporting.

References: http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-publish-html-tutorial.html#sec-6

Comment: I've mostly been doing `head -4 $(date -v -1d +"%F").org > $(date +"%F").org && emacs $(date +"%F").org` to copy my header into a new file, but yours is a more elegant solution.